# MVC 5 Using POSTAL with Models

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5.2, postal

I am trying to use Postal in Mvc.5.2.3 and Razor.3.2.3 in Visual studio Ultimate 2013, I have many forms to generate for this project and would like to use Views as i would like to Post content to a database as well as send an email out with the information from the form using Postal. I am also creating partial Views for the header and footer so they are always the same and only the content of the email is changed by what forms are used. The email that will be sent will be to the sales department for review, a second email needs to be sent to the person that filled out the form saying thank you and showing the information they sent with the form. I hope this makes sense. I had the database working properly but had so much trouble getting the email system to work i have just started over and just trying to get the email system working properly.

My Model

```
    using Postal;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;


    namespace APP.Models.Forms.Company
    {


        public class ContactEmail : Email
        {
          public ContactEmail() : base("Contact")
          { }

          public int ContactId { get; set; }
          public Guid TicketId { get; set; }

          [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter your First Name!")]
          [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
          [DisplayName("First Name")]
          [Display(Order = 1)]
          public string FirstName { get; set; }

          [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter your Last Name!")]
          [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
          [DisplayName("Last Name")]
          [Display(Order = 2)]
          public string LastName { get; set; }

          [DisplayName("Business Name")]
          [Display(Order = 3)]
          public string BusinessName { get; set; }


          [Required(ErrorMessage = "You have not entered a phone numer, Please enter your phone number so we can get back to you!")]
          [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
          [DisplayName("Phone Number")]
          [RegularExpression(@"^[01]?[- .]?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter proper format of one of the following: (555)555-5555, 555-555-5555, 5555555555")]
          [StringLength(32)]
          [Display(Order = 4)]
          public string Phone { get; set; }

          [Required(ErrorMessage = "You have not entered an Email address, Please enter your email address!")]
          [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
          [DisplayName("Email Address")]
          [MaxLength(50)]
          [RegularExpression(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$", ErrorMessage = "The Email field is not valid, Please enter a valid email address!")]
          [Display(Order = 5)]
          public string UserEmailAddress { get; set; }

          [Required(ErrorMessage = "You have not entered a message, Please enter a message!")]
          [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
          [StringLength(2000)]
          [DisplayName("Message")]
          [Display(Order = 6)]
          public string Message { get; set; }

          public Source Source { get; set; }


          public HttpPostedFileBase Upload { get; set; }


          [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
          public string FullName
          {
              get
              {
                  return LastName + ", " + FirstName;
              }
          }

      }

  }
```

The Controler:

```
    using APP.Models;
    using APP.Models.Forms.Company;
    using Postal;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace APP.Controllers
    {
        public class FormsController : Controller
        {
            private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            #region Main Forms Page
            // Forms Page Blank with unautherized access
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
            #endregion


            #region Contact_Form
            // GET: Forms/Create
            public ActionResult Contact()
            {

                return View();
            }

            // POST: Forms/Submit


            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Send(ContactEmail form)
            {

                var email = new Email("Contact")
                {
                    To = "webmaster@somedomain.com",
                    MyModel = ContactEmail //Says its a "type" but used like a variable.


                }
                email.Send();



            }



    #endregion

    #region Condo Form
    #endregion

    #region Personal Flood Form
    #endregion

    #region Home Insurance Form
    #endregion

    #region Renters Insurance Form
    #endregion

    #region WaterCraft Insurance Form
    #endregion

    #region Life Insurance Form
    #endregion

    #region Business Flood Form
    #endregion

    #region Business Risk Form
    #endregion

    #region Business Inland Marine Form
    #endregion

    #region Business Group Health Form
    #endregion

    #region Form
    #endregion

    #region Not Available Forms Page
    // Forms Page Blank with unautherized access
    public ActionResult Not_Available()
    {
        return View();
    }
    #endregion

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Form View:

```
    @model APP.Models.Forms.Company.ContactEmail


    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_LandingPages.cshtml";
    }
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Contact Form</h2>


        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Contact </h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BusinessName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BusinessName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BusinessName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserEmailAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserEmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div></div>


            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" class="btn btn-default" />&emsp;
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset Form" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        }

        <div>


            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Home")
        </div>
    </div>


    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

My email View is Contact.cshtml and is located in the email folder under Views.

Comment: I am also Confused on how to call both actions email and save to database. and i saw how to use tasks, so will be looking into using it.

Comment: Also i cant seam to use @Url.Action in my views, Has this changed in MVC 5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have an email object, so just call send:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Send(ContactEmail form)
{
    form.Send();

    // You could also save this to the database here...
}
```